# Go back and forth on Dynamic websites?

Tags: jquery, django

I'm building a single-page website in Django where I use a lot of Jquery/Ajax to load content dynamically into divs.

For example, I load search results into a div. Then when I click a listed object I load that object into the same div. But now I want to go back to the same search-results again.

What is the technique/design-pattern to handle this on dynamic websites?

Comment: Hi! I'm not a web programmer but I think the problem you described is known as the "ajax back button problem". You can find many resources on the web if you google this.

Comment: The simplest solution is to keep the search configuration in a JS object and provide a link in your "detail" view that triggers that same search to be run again. Or, if you truly want to go "back" (ignoring intermediate changes) you could push each JSON response into an array and go "back" to that. Lots of pretty easy solutions to maintaining search state, just depends on exactly what you want to accomplish.